# Is it fine to have NS and A record for the host name

Tags: domain-name-system, a-record

I just registered a domain on Route 53 and the record set didn't have an A record for the hostname (assume it example.com). It just had an NS record for "example.com", listing the nameservers. Although, there was an A record for www.example.com.

The website loads fine while visiting www.example.com, but returned nothing on visiting example.com. Hence I added an A record for it with the same IP address for www.

It's working now. So, I want to know whether the correct thing has been done. Are both these A and NS records different, and need to set this way?

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly correct and the proper way to do it.

The A record is the mapping of a hostname to an IP address. You can have multiple A records.

The NS record tells the world which servers will answer questions about other hostnames within the example.com domain. They need to match the list of nameservers that your DNS registrar has for your domain.

You probably also want an MX record, which will tell the world what servers will accept mail for your domain.

If you want to verify that your DNS zone is correct, you can go to https://zonemaster.iis.se and enter your domain name, and it will check to verify that everything is in order.